# How do I use C headers from libgit2 without getting this error?

Tags: c, linux, git, libgit2

I took everything from include/git2 to /usr/include, then tried compiling the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <repository.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with GCC, I get the following error:

```
maxwell@UNIX-PC:~$ gcc ok.c
In file included from /usr/include/common.h:16:0,
                 from /usr/include/repository.h:10,
                 from ok.c:2:
/usr/include/inttypes.h:33:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
In file included from /usr/include/inttypes.h:46:0,
                 from /usr/include/common.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/repository.h:10,
                 from ok.c:2:
/usr/include/stdint.h:33:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
In file included from /usr/include/inttypes.h:46:0,
                 from /usr/include/common.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/repository.h:10,
                 from ok.c:2:
/usr/include/stdint.h:89:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘int64_t’
/usr/include/stdint.h:90:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘uint64_t’
/usr/include/stdint.h:101:1: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
/usr/include/stdint.h:111:1: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
/usr/include/stdint.h:124:1: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
In file included from /usr/include/common.h:16:0,
                 from /usr/include/repository.h:10,
                 from ok.c:2:
/usr/include/inttypes.h:282:1: error: unknown type name ‘_inline’
/usr/include/inttypes.h:284:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__cdecl’
/usr/include/inttypes.h:284:11: error: unknown type name ‘__cdecl’
```

I see the error that says only to use inttypes.h only with Visual Studio, so how do I call repository.h from a program compiled with GCC? I really want to use some data structures defined in repository.h. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You reported this issue on github few hours ago. Didn't you?

Comment: @linquize Yep, but then I decided that this was more appropriate here so I closed it on Github and posted this.

Comment: Right! libgit2 is built by build server (Travis CI) when a pull request on github is open. It can verify whether the code is good to build. So it is less likely to break the build of such a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, you should use the build system to install the headers. These headers aren't made to be included themselves. If you want to use libgit2, you should include `git2.h`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that some header files were overwritten when you copied eveything from include/git2 to /usr/include.

```
In file included from /usr/include/common.h:16:0,
                 from /usr/include/repository.h:10,
                 from ok.c:2:
/usr/include/inttypes.h:33:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual   C++ compilers!"
```

The right approach is to use gcc's `-Iinclude_path` option to include the other header files, and use "-D macro_def" to define the macros that are to be used with the preprocessor.

```
gcc -I repository_h_path  -D some_macro  ok.c
```

You might want to refer to [search path](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) in gcc documentation.

Comment: Yikes, so how do I get my old header files back? I do not have any backups.

Comment: You can re-install gcc. Check the gcc version and reinstall it.