# Failing to install python 3.6.3 from source: recipe for target 'Programs/python.o' failed

Tags: python, linux

I run Linux mint 18.2, `./configure` is working Ok, but when I do `make` I get the following:

```
gcc -pthread -c -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers   -I. -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Programs/python.o ./Programs/python.c
In file included from ./Include/pyport.h:6:0,
                 from ./Include/Python.h:50,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
/usr/local/include/inttypes.h:38:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
 #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
  ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/inttypes.h:48:0,
                 from ./Include/pyport.h:6,
                 from ./Include/Python.h:50,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:38:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
 #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
  ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/inttypes.h:48:0,
                 from ./Include/pyport.h:6,
                 from ./Include/Python.h:50,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:135:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘int64_t’
 typedef signed __int64       int64_t;
                              ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:136:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘uint64_t’
 typedef unsigned __int64     uint64_t;
                              ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:147:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
 typedef uint64_t  uint_least64_t;
         ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:157:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
 typedef uint64_t  uint_fast64_t;
         ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:164:30: error: conflicting types for ‘intptr_t’
    typedef _W64 signed int   intptr_t;
                              ^
In file included from ./Include/Python.h:36:0,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
/usr/include/unistd.h:270:20: note: previous declaration of ‘intptr_t’ was here
 typedef __intptr_t intptr_t;
                    ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/inttypes.h:48:0,
                 from ./Include/pyport.h:6,
                 from ./Include/Python.h:50,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:170:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
 typedef uint64_t  uintmax_t;
         ^
In file included from ./Include/pyport.h:6:0,
                 from ./Include/Python.h:50,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
/usr/local/include/inttypes.h:288:1: error: unknown type name ‘_inline’
 _inline
 ^
/usr/local/include/inttypes.h:290:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__cdecl’
 imaxdiv_t __cdecl imaxdiv(intmax_t numer, intmax_t denom)
           ^
/usr/local/include/inttypes.h:290:11: error: unknown type name ‘__cdecl’
In file included from ./Include/Python.h:71:0,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
./Include/pyhash.h:64:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
         uint64_t k0;
         ^
./Include/pyhash.h:65:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
         uint64_t k1;
         ^
In file included from ./Include/Python.h:79:0,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
./Include/longintrepr.h:47:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
 typedef uint64_t twodigits;
         ^
In file included from ./Include/Python.h:87:0,
                 from ./Programs/python.c:3:
./Include/dictobject.h:31:5: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
     uint64_t ma_version_tag;
     ^
Makefile:750: recipe for target 'Programs/python.o' failed
make: *** [Programs/python.o] Error 1
```

I had successfully built previous versions of python on the same machine, having no clue what's wrong with this one, 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Python problem. For some reason you ended up with copies of [*Windows* include files for integer definitions](https://github.com/chemeris/msinttypes):

```
/usr/local/include/inttypes.h:38:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
 #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
  ^
```

and

```
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:38:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
 #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
  ^
```

Everything else flows from those two errors. Clean up your system, those include files should not be there, in standard locations.

I've seen reports of various projects including those headers in their source code repository, with people copying these wholesale into standard locations. See [How do I use C headers from libgit2 without getting this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910801/how-do-i-use-c-headers-from-libgit2-without-getting-this-error) (*when you copied eveything from include/git2 to /usr/include*) and [#error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers" in CodeBlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005607/error-use-this-header-only-with-microsoft-visual-c-compilers-in-codeblocks).  However they ended up on your system, they don't belong there.

Comment: That helped, thanks! I completely removed those 2 files and then did:

`$ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall`
`$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev`

and re-built python